# Biblatex: How can I get same bibliography when compiling region in AUCTEX as in the complete "master" document?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, pdftex, auctex

#### Preliminary remark

This problem is constantly annoying me, so I'd like to find a solution. From my experience with `biber` I thought I would just need to copy/rename some files created by `bibtex` to make it work (see my examples below), but with `bibtex` it seems to be not that easy.
So my second idea seems more practical: extracting the list of cited references and then citing all of them with a `nocite` command (see details of my idea below):

## Background of my question

I'm often using the "compile region" command in `Emacs auctex-mode` to compile only the current paragraph and quickly see, if my editing had the wished result.

However, citations are not handled properly, as in the region there is only a subset of the references cited, so the numeric citekey [95] is different (and that can have also consequences on linebreaks and typesetting.

So I'd like to find a way to let the region use the same (long) list of references as the complete document and cite accordingly.

## Some ideas for a solution (my knowledge is not sufficient to make it work automagically)

- Maybe it would make sense to regularly extract all cited references from the main document and then somehow add a `\nocite{ref1, ref2, ... ref350}` command to the region file.
  Maybe I should create a custom bibliography file for the main file and just add `\nocite{*}` to the preamble. This would only be problematic when citing new references, then I would have to refresh the custom .bib file...

  - how can I extract the cited references of the master document?
  - can I modify the region file in `auctex` and append a `\nocite{ref1, ref2, ..., refn)` command, which uses the extracted list of references?
  - alternatively: could I create a custom bibliography file for the master file which only contains the cited references and then add `\nocite{*}` to my preamble?
    But then: what if I would remove all citations of one of those references from the text body? Can I then still find out in the aux files, which ones are only cited via `nocite` and which ones are really cited by a `\cite{)` (or similar) command?
- Can I copy some of the original files to `_region_....` and thus let the region use the same bibliography order and numbers?
- If I copy the .aux file from the main document to `_region_.aux`, I get the correct numbering of my references, but this aux file is overwritten at each latex run.
  Furthermore, typesetting/placing of some tables and floats like longtables etc. might take 2 pdflatex runs and by just overwriting the .aux file before each pdflatex run, I assume I'd loose information necessary for the second pdflatex run.
- the order and numbering of the references seems to be written in lines like this one: `\abx@aux@number{25}{chiu}{0}{20}`. Might it make sense to grab just those lines from the aux file of the complete document and append them to the `_region_.aux` file?
  I am not successful with my large document, as those lines seem to be overwritten each time I compile with `pdflatex`.
  I tried like that: `grep -i \abx@aux@number main.aux >> _region_.aux`, but that has no effect - particularly, as in *region*.aux there are no similar lines created if I compile the document from `auctex`, but still the same source gets another numerical cite key...

## Example

### Main file `BibtexRegion_FullDocument.tex`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8, defernumbers, useprefix,firstinits=true, maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}  % für bessere Literaturverzeichnisse
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}



\begin{document}

\nocite{*}


This document has 2 paragraphs. This is the first one.

This is the second one and it cites \textcite{chiu}.

 \printbibliography


\end{document}
```

- this works in with TeXLive 2014, as it uses the `biblatex` example bibliography.

result: `\cite{chiu}` becomes [20]
[image]

### Auctex creates the following region file `_region_.tex`:

If I only mark the second paragraph, and compile the region, `auctex` creates the following tex file

```
\message{ !name(BibtexRegion_FullDocument.tex)}

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=numeric-comp, backend=bibtex8, defernumbers, useprefix,firstinits=true, maxnames=99, maxcitenames=3]{biblatex}  % für bessere Literaturverzeichnisse
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}



\begin{document}

\message{ !name(BibtexRegion_FullDocument.tex) !offset(4) }
This is the second one and it cites \textcite{chiu}.
\message{ !name(BibtexRegion_FullDocument.tex) !offset(6) }

\end{document}
```

**Result: `\cite{chiu}` becomes [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTX7J.png) - how can I get [20] here too?**

[image]

### Files in directory

```
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin     306  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument-blx.bib
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin    3933  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.aux
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin   84175  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.bbl
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin    1986  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.blg
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin   14524  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.log
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin      39  6 Mär 11:01 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.out
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin  114343  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.pdf
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin    2765  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.run.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin   50679  6 Mär 11:05 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.synctex.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin     433  6 Mär 11:04 BibtexRegion_FullDocument.tex
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin     306  6 Mär 11:06 _region_-blx.bib
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin     495  6 Mär 11:06 _region_.aux
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin    1394  6 Mär 11:05 _region_.bbl
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin    1770  6 Mär 11:05 _region_.blg
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin   13209  6 Mär 11:06 _region_.log
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin       0  6 Mär 11:03 _region_.out
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin   13426  6 Mär 11:06 _region_.pdf
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin    2612  6 Mär 11:06 _region_.run.xml
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin     942  6 Mär 11:06 _region_.synctex.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 mbg4  admin     508  6 Mär 11:05 _region_.tex
```

Comment: Compile region feature is intended as a quick overview of the final output, but don't expect it to be completely reliable (reference numbering is an example).  What you want to do is closer to what `\include`+`\includeonly` does.

Comment: I see, but shouldn't it be generally possible to trick the aux files of the region to get the above mentioned result? With biber, I had made it work already, but unfortunately I have to use bibtex8 at the moment and I'm not sure how to get the relevant information into the right place.

Comment: You can replace `_region_.aux` with `BibtexRegion_FullDocument.aux`, run latex with `C-c C-r` just once and view the output.  But you should do this every time before running latex with `C-c C-r`, as this always overwrites the auxiliary file.

Comment: don't I also have to replace the files produced by `bibtex` or are the original files linked by the copied .aux file?

Comment: One more thought: if I can only do 1 pdflatex run on the document, I can not compile it to a final state, right (if there are things like floats or table columns which need more than one run to typeset. I found in the `.aux` file that lines like `\abx@aux@number{25}{chiu}{0}{20}` seem to carry the bibliographic information and if (in my example) I append those lines to the _region_.aux file, I get the correct numbering of my references.

Comment: @giordano: see my edit in the question

Comment: I'm no expert, I don't know what to do apart from replacing the aux file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it seems that I overlooked a quite easy solution:

`cp BibtexRegion_FullDocument.bbl _region_.bbl`

after a full compilation of the complete document seems to work fine.

However, it is not possible (nor does it make sense) to run `bibtex` on the region, because then this bbl file would be overwritten and the information lost.